# Drools maven upgrade issue with float fields from 7.54.* version and up

Tags: maven, upgrade, precision, drools

Issue scenario:-
I am facing an issue with drools maven upgrade from 7.54.* version on words with the float type fields where the particular float fields having number(starting,middle or ending) in it's name.

Ex:- float123,fl123oat.

So the issue is when am trying to comparing the above type of fields with the same numbers which is the float field having in it's name, am getting restriction by drools and the condition getting failed irrespective of operators am using (=,<,>,<=,>=,...)

Ex:- float123 > 123

And drools manipulating the rule condition like below

float123.0 (wrong) > 123.0

Note :- This is specific to the float field name which is having number in it's name and when we are comparing with same number/ numbers where the float field name having.

Problem that drools creating:-
Instead of converting the comparing value (123), it's ending up updating field name (float123.0) and as we don't have float123.0 field name defined in our pojo classes we are getting the unknown field error.

Workaround:-
Since we are unable to remove the restriction from java code side,we opted to enter decimal value(123.0) with comparision of specific float field (float123) wrt to all specific conditions.

Ex:- float123 > 123.0

This is working as expected since drools no need to manipulate the comparing value in background as we are comparing float field with decimal value as expected by drools like above example.

Problem after applying workaround:

But this workaround is breaking when we add multiple rule conditions by applying only with OR (||) operator and it's working expected with AND (&) operator.
The example scenarios given as below

Ex:- 1.float123 > 123 - fail

2.float123 > 123.0 - pass

3.float123 > 456 - pass

4.float123 > 123.0 & float456 < 456   - fail

5.float123 > 123.0 & float456 < 456.0 - pass

6.float123 > 123.0 || float456 < 456 - pass (which is wrong)

7.float123 > 123.0 || float456 < 456.0 - pass

8.float123 > 123 || float456 < 456 - pass (which is wrong)

9.float123 > 123 & float456 < 456 || float789 = 789 - pass (which is wrong)

Irrespective of wrong conditions with in the complex rules,always rules passing when we combined the rules with || operator which is wrong.

The Ask:-

1. First of all is there anyway to take out that restriction from drools from java side ,we are facing this from 5.54 to 7.74(tested till this version) and if we are having any advanced version that fixing the issue.

2.Is there any reason/workaround or fix for the || operator behaving different from single and & operator scenarios.

I Debug into more and could find out that below peace of code causing the issue.

Public static KieContainer pdc(KieServices ks,string droolsScript)
{
KieFileSystem kfs= ks.newKieFileSystem;

KieBuilder kb=ks.newKieBuilder(kfs).
buildAll();

Results rs= kb.getResults();
}

If rs returning errors in it,the rule /rules validation is failing.

Error in logs :-

when we are testing it through unit test we are getting below error.i am just giving simple rule example.ERROR ******.KieProject - unable to build kieBaseModel:defaultKieBase Unable to resolve method using strict-mode:java.lang.Float.0()] Near :{..float123.0 >123.0...}

G lad if you can post your findings/analysis and advices to fix the issues.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: To be honest I simply don't understand your problem? Are we talking about versions of artifacts or are we talking about Java code? (`But this workaround is breaking when we add multiple rule conditions by ap..`?) ???

Comment: I too am struggling to follow what the problem is. Can you simply post: 1. the rule or rules (DRL); 2. a unit test firing the rule, with expected inputs/outputs and actual outputs; 3. the dependencies section of your pom.xml ?

Comment: @khmarbaise, the problem is due to updating the version of artifacts the existing java code behaving differently .i have added the code for the same.the rule/rules validation failing now where the validations were passing before updating the version.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas,1.we have the choice of adding 1 or more rules.the one rule scenario and when we add multiple rules with && conditions with the updated maven drools version it's failing where we must compare the float123 with 1.0 to make rule passing.but when we use || condition b/w to rules the entire rule(failrule||failrule  ) passing.added more examples above.

Comment: 2.when we are testing it through unit test we are getting below error.i am just giving simple rule example.ERROR ******.KieProject - unable to build 
kieBaseModel:defaultKieBase Unable to resolve method using strict-mode:java.lang.Float.0()] Near :{..float123.0 >123.0...}

Comment: 3.dependency version of pom.xml <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
    <version>7.73.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Please modify your question using the 'edit' link at the bottom to add the information.